# Using redux in same Component in SPA

Tags: single-page-application, redux

We can assume that: we have a SPA application consist of a `profile` page and a `followerList` page. The state tree is as shown in the following:

```
{
  profile: { name: xx, sex: xx },
  followerList: []
}
```

We can open a follower list page from a profile **page A**, and then open a profile **page B** from the follower list page. In my application, page A and page B share the same reducer `profile`.

Here is the problem: when page B rendered, the `profile` in state tree has been changed by B's info; when it returns back to page A, it is supposed to keep A's info, **but it has also been rendered by B's info**.

---

So far I've got two solutions:

1. Using a `profileList` to keep all profile pages have been opened. It means that I have to keep a list for every page which can be opened recursively. Caching profile data is really a good method, which is also very helpful to cut the request. But it means that I have to **make the state tree more complex**, and inject more concept (e.g. **reselect**). As I'm building the architecture of our app, increasing the complexity is not friendly to other developer.
2. Re-rendering the profile page when the page is returned. I don't think it's an elegant way.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you keep 2 `followers` list in the state?

Comment: @Florent thank you for your comment. Do you mean that I have to keep a list for every page which can be opened recursively?

Comment: It depends on your use case. I suggest you to edit your question and to add more info/code about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Florent It's just a fictional scene....OK, I'll try to add more code